# Traduire « overkill »

Tags: traduction, anglais, adjectifs, tropes

Si je veux caractériser une solution comme étant exagérée pour le besoin existant, par exemple « *this solution is an overkill* », quels autres mots que *exagéré* pourrait être utilisés ?

Comment: Parfois, c'est de l'overkill de chercher une bonne traduction quand le mot anglais est compris de tous.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On peut utiliser le mot "disproportionné". Qui va au-delà de ce qui est nécessaire.

Answer (score 7):

Je suggérerais peut-être également l'adjectif *excessif*, qui surpasse les attentes.

Answer (score 6):

Les matheux affectionnent particulièrement *utiliser un marteau-piqueur pour tuer une mouche*.

Comment: je la connaissais sous la forme d'"'utiliser un porte avion pour la chasse aux canards "

Comment: Ah bon ? J'ai toujours dit *un marteau-pilon*, et je ne trouve pas que ce soit spécifique aux matheux. Google Books trouve des [marteaux-pilons](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22marteau-pilon%20pour%20%C3%A9craser%20une%20mouche%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_fr) mais pas de [marteau-piqueur](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22marteau-piqueur%20pour%20%C3%A9craser%20une%20mouche%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_fr).

Comment: @Gilles: Je l'ai déjà entendu chez des informaticiens aussi. Mais bon, ce sont un peu des cousins ;)

Comment: Ah, de mon coté c'est mon prof de physique qui employait l'expression tout azimuts (mais certes il s'adressait à des matheux). Par contre je rejoins Gilles, c'est *marteau-pilon* qu'il employait.

Comment: Ce n'était pas plutôt utiliser _[un canon pour tuer une mouche](http://www.e-frenchtranslation.com/fr/proverbes_2.htm#Mouche,%20puce%20et%20autre)_?

Comment: Le Wikitionnaire semble aimer *[écraser une mouche avec un marteau](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9craser_une_mouche_avec_un_marteau)*.

Answer (score 4):

On pourrait aussi dire *surdimensionnée*, si dans la solution il y a une grandeur quantifiable.

Answer (score 1):

En complément à "disproportionné" et "excessif", qui sont de bonnes réponses, je propose d'ajouter la notion de gâchis ou d'inutilité, présente dans l'anglais "overkill"  en plus de la notion d'excès.

On peut penser à

- Une solution *inutilement complexe* (ou coûteuse)
- Un *gaspillage de ressources* par rapport au problème à résoudre

Dans les expressions imagées, on peut penser à l'expression sarcastique *pourquoi faire simple quand on peut faire compliqué ?*